# How to set class name dynamically and retain its value?

Tags: jquery, css, razor

I have created partial view which will be called every 20 seconds until it satisfies the condition. This view contains a status bar and based on condition it will change the status.

**Code:**

```
<ol class="progress-tracker" data-progress-tracker-steps="4">
    <li class="progress-tracker-initial">Received</li>
    <li class="@(Model.JobStatus == (DeliveryRequestStatus) DeliveryManagerCallback.OrderStatus.Kitchen ? "progress-tracker-done" : "progress-tracker-todo")">Kitchen</li>
    <li class="@(Model.JobStatus == (DeliveryRequestStatus) DeliveryManagerCallback.OrderStatus.Road ? "progress-tracker-done" : "progress-tracker-todo")">In Transit</li>
    <li class="@(Model.JobStatus == (DeliveryRequestStatus) DeliveryManagerCallback.OrderStatus.Delivered ? "progress-tracker-done" : "progress-tracker-todo")">Delivered</li>
</ol>
```

**UI:**

[image]

The problem I am running into is, when the status changes to In-transit from Kitchen, I am loosing the style for kitchen which is expected based on my condition. How can I retain the styling when status changes?

- Should I use some condition which overwrites the defined class?
- Do I need to add jQuery code to update the class?

I can add `CSS` code if needed.

**Actual Result:**

[image]

**Expected Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `Model.JobStatus` has only one value so you cannot check it for equality for more than one `OrderStatus`. Here you need sequence comparison to solve the issue.

So let's say if you have `OrderStatus` enum like

```
enum OrderStatus
{
   Received= 1,
   Kitchen = 2,
   Road = 3,
   Delivered = 4
}
```

and you model's `JobStatus` property has a value from that enum, you can do something like this to achieve what you want.

```
<ol class="progress-tracker" data-progress-tracker-steps="4">
    <li class="progress-tracker-initial">Received</li>
    <li class="@((int)Model.JobStatus >= (int) DeliveryManagerCallback.OrderStatus.Kitchen ? "progress-tracker-done" : "progress-tracker-todo")">Kitchen</li>
    <li class="@((int)Model.JobStatus >= (int) DeliveryManagerCallback.OrderStatus.Road ? "progress-tracker-done" : "progress-tracker-todo")">In Transit</li>
    <li class="@((int)Model.JobStatus >= (int) DeliveryManagerCallback.OrderStatus.Delivered ? "progress-tracker-done" : "progress-tracker-todo")">Delivered</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This is what I wanted. Thank you.